# Not able to capture the packets, getting stop iteration error after upgradation of pyshark 0.3.6 from 0.3.5

Tags: python-2.7

I am executing the code below and I am getting stop iteration error after upgrading pyshark to 0.3.6.

Code:
import sys, os
import pyshark
import time

class Wireshark_traces_Sbc:
        ROBOT_SCOPE_GLOBAL="Testsuite"

```
    def interface_File_Capture(self,file):
        return pyshark.FileCapture()

    def interface_Live_Capture(self,filtertype=None):
        self.cap=pyshark.LiveCapture(display_filter=filtertype)
        self.cap.interfaces=['Local Area Connection' , 'VM1']
        self.d=self.cap.sniff_continuously()
        print("Wireshark started") 
        print self.d
        self.d.next()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Error Message:
NW1(Xlite) to NW2(CISCO) :: *** Test Case to automate a Call hold ... 1. \Device\NPF_{2D0B37C1-B5B8-472C-BC9E-
2DBDB04C661A} (VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter)
2. \Device\NPF_{7A249E6F-9177-4C37-965F-BC29EA2F3502} (Microsoft)
3. \Device\NPF_{8F2E6B4C-6910-459C-AE3A-ADA28BCAD774} (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM)
4. \Device\NPF_{21B269B3-38C2-4FF5-ACD0-A5A5F1EDA01C} (VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter)
NW1(Xlite) to NW2(CISCO) :: *** Test Case to automate a Call hold ... | FAIL |
StopIteration

Could you please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
-kranti

Comment: Can any one guide me here please